# Programs keep freezing for few seconds

Tags: windows-7, freeze, windows-update

So I installed a huge chunk of Windows Updates a month ago. After that my active programs ,such as Firefox or MSN, have been freezing (Not responding) for few seconds and then coming back to life. I've been trying to search for specific update that is causing this, but haven't found anything. I've also scanned my computer with no infections, so I am almost positive it's some Windows Update because it has happened since updating.

It has started becoming very frustrating, when programs constantly freeze. It has also made my computer freeze few times, when leaving it on overnight. After my screen goes black, the computer freezes and when I wake up and restart screen and move my mouse, I see that time still it at "00:40" for ex. when the real time is "10:39". My mouse and keyboard stop working and I have no other option but to force reboot computer.

Could there be a specific Windows Update I could uninstall to make this work? I have 142GB avaible on my hard drive and 8GB RAM, and I have Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

A computer freezing overnight, or its time changing, and keyboard/mouse/monitor stop working are usually not signs of a corrupt windows update.  However, there are some things that you can do to help narrow down the suspects.

**Check Logs:** 
Check your system log; Check both the application and system log.  Check both the application, system, and forwarded events logs.  Did i mention to check your logs?   Very important to check your logs!  Usually does a wonderful job as to finding out WHAT is causing the crash, and what dll/program/entry/service/application is causing the issue.

**Other Possible Steps**

1. Assuming you have Windows XP +, you could try doing a system restore JUST PRIOR to the Windows Updates you performed.  This would ensure that  you roll back your system to how it was operating prior to doing the huge chunk of updates, and then allow you to install them in smaller patches.
2. Run a scan with Dr. Web CureIt.  While many programs out there, Microsoft Security Essentials, Norton Internet Security, Trend Micro, Kapersky, McAffee are all....good....programs to run from time to time on the system, they do frequently miss rootkits and other types of virus injectors and spawners that may already be on the system.  DWC takes care of that for you by doing an enhanced scan that is capable of detecting these infections.
3. Run MalwareBytes Anti-Malware.  This is something you may have already done, however, I would recommend you run this program with full administrative rights, in a diagnostic startup mode.  Meaning, `start` -> `run` -> `msconfig` -> `Click Startup tab, click 'disable all'`, (re-enable any items for your wireless network if you use wirieless to connect), then click on the `'Services'` tab, and click the `check box at the bottom 'hide all microsoft services'`, and then click `'disable all'` (re-enable any wireless services if you use wireless to connect).  Then reboot, and run MBAM to see if any infections exist.
4. Open up a command prompt with administrative privileges (Vista/7:  Start -> cmd -> right Click -> run as admin):  Then to clear all of your temp files:  `rd /s /q %temp%` <-- type that into the box and press enter.  While it may seem like a drastic step, it is a necessary command to run from time to time.  When installing large blocks of updates, the `%temp%` folder can become quite large, and hard to manage for the system.
5. Run 'AutoRuns' from Microsoft (you can simply Google it and run it from the SysInternals online Suite), and check for any programs, applications, startups, entries you do not want, etc on startup.
6. Run 'HijackThis' from Trend, to see if there are any suspicious system entries on your computer.

Above all else, a system that is acting odd after a Windows Update usually smacks of an infection to me.  And, being in the computer industry for (sighs, almost 2 decades, lol), I have seen my fair share of updates triggering latent viruses and worms.  Always best to check these methods FIRST, and then consider taking it in, or wiping the slate with an FFR (Fresh Format Re-install) of the operating system.